# Doctrine|ORM|Symfony: Is possible relation to Interface or multiple entities

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, mapping, relationship

Simple example:
I've got two users Admin and Client (both implements UserInterface) and Cart - three entity classes at a. Admin and Client can have his own carts. How to configure/resolve Cart entity relation to have method 'getUser()' which returns Admin or Client user?

Maybe I can have column user_id and second column with user entity name in Cart (something similar as DiscriminatorMapping can do)?

```
    class Admin implements UserInterface
    {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    
    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cart", mappedBy="???")
     */
    private $carts;
    ....
```

```
    class Client implements UserInterface
    {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    
    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cart", mappedBy="???")
     */
    private $carts;
    ....
```

```
    class Cart
    {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    
    /**
     * @var UserInterface
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserInterface", ???)
     */
    private $user;
    ....
```

I tried [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) Doctrine feature, also tried [DisciminatorMapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#discriminatormap) and composite keys (join by multiple columns) option with no luck.

Any help?

Comment: I have the same problem have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you were almost there. DiscriminatorMapping is probably the way to go. However, you need to bind Client and Admin to a Parent class. So consider this hierarchy:

User (parent class)

- Admin (extends User)
- Client (extends User)

Then in your Cart entity you bind the relation to the User entity.